# Разные результаты при перестановке множителя в C++

Tags: c++, стандарт, арифметика

У меня есть такие фрагменты кода:

```
int n = 14, k = 5; 
cout << n/k * 2;
```

и

```
int n = 14, k = 5; 
cout << 2 * n/k;
```

Первый выдает 4, а второй 5.
Почему так?

Answer (score 2):

Приоритеты умножения и деления одинаковы, операторы левоассоциативны, так что операции выполняются поочередно слева направо.

```
n/k*2 = 14/5*2 = 2*2 = 4

2*n/k = 2*14/5 = 28/5 = 5
```

Вы же помните, что такое целочисленное деление?